milvus-2.3.11 error="incomplete query result, missing id xxxxxxx, len(searchIDs) amd64
We are getting frequent errors like below and our searches are failing:
"Error received from Milvus from method:
getData: incomplete query result, missing id f3aecfdf-c3e6-4082-84e1-6f67c83d3c41, len(searchIDs) = 200, len(queryIDs) = 155, collection=450749972193045101"
We found some relevant issue here: https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/issues/34021
Is the issue being addressed?
Can we expect a fix backported to 2.3.11?

It's under fix. But I don't think it will backported to 2.3.11, since we only backport to latest 2.3.x version.
